# Why am I Seeing Summer 2016 API errors with the Summer 18 version of the Salesforce Migration Tool?

Tags: metadata-api, migration-tool

I am trying to download the latest version of the force.com migration tool (sometimes called the ANT migration tool.)

The [download page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm) seems to link to the Summer 2016 version of the tool (see errors below), despite claiming to link to the Summer 2018 version.

When I configure `package.xml` and run the `.jar` like so:

`ant retrieveUnpackaged -lib path/to/ant-salesforce.jar`

I get errors like this:

`[sf:retrieve] package.xml - API version Summer '16 does not have access to Lightning Pages of type CommObjectPage`

Note that this error message is not referring to the API version in the retrieve source sandbox. The sandbox API version is Winter '19.

I've been looking for a while now and still haven't found an alternative download link that correctly points at the Summer 2018 migration tool. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a link to [download ant migration tool 43.0](https://gs0.salesforce.com/dwnld/SfdcAnt/salesforce_ant_43.0.zip)

looks like your problem is, that you selected 37.0 API versdion on the top left corner.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Tried your direct download link for version 43. Unfortunately, I got the same `Summer 16` error messages. I've also checked the version in the top left as you suggested-- all pointing at version 43.

Comment: @Nick what API version is mentioned in your `package.xml`?

Comment: The API version was sert at 37.0. When I changed it to 43.0 the errors disappeared. Many thanks!